# Non-basic pseudo-elementary class

Tags: model-theory

Is there a pseudo-elementary class, which is not an elementary class itself, of structures which is not basic pseudo-elementary, that is, is not the reduct of a basic elementary class?

Comment: A basic elementary class is an elementary class where $T=\{\varphi\}$ for a single sentence $\varphi$?

Comment: @user27454 Yes.

Comment: I have the feeling that if $\mathcal{K}$ is the elementary class of real closed fields, and $\Gamma$ is the pseudo-elementary class of their additive groups, then $\Gamma$ is not the reduct of a basic elementary class. However, the problem will consist in proving the last part.

Comment: To avoid a trivial solution, you presumably want to assume that the language is finite?

Comment: @Alex Kruckman Yes, the language should be finite. Also, I would be happy if someone also gave an example of an elementary class which is not basic pseudo-elementary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $\mathbb{K}$ is a basic pseudoelementary class in a finite language, then $Th(\mathbb{K})$ is recursively enumerable: $Th(\mathbb{K})$ consists exactly of those sentences in that language which are provable from $\varphi$ (where $\mathbb{K}$ is the set of reducts of models of $\{\varphi\}$). So any non-recursively enumerable, deductively-closed set of sentences in a finite language provides an elementary class which is not basic pseudoelementary.

For a natural example, we can take $\mathbb{K}$ to be the set of models of [true arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_arithmetic).

Comment: And what about a non-elementary psuedoelementary class which is not basic psuedoelementary.

Comment: @user107952 Just consider the "fusion" of an elementary non-basic-pseudoelementary class with a non-elementary pseudoelementary class. Specifically, let $K_1$ be an elementary non-basic-pseudoelementary class in a finite language $L_1$, $K_2$ be a non-elementary pseudo-elementary class in a disjoint finite language $L_2$, and let $K$ be the set of $L_1\sqcup L_2$-structures whose $L_1$-part is in $K_1$ and whose $L_2$-part is in $K_2$.

Comment: And what is the proof that your construction is an answer to my question?

Comment: @user107952 You mean the construction in my comment above? If $\mathbb{I}$ is the set of reducts to $L$ of $\mathbb{J}$, and $\mathbb{I}$ is not basic pseudoelementary, then neither is $\mathbb{J}$ (since we could always have "reduced further"). And to show that the non-elementarity of $K_2$ transfers to $K$, use the fact that if $T$ is a theory in  a finite language $S=S_1\sqcup S_2$ and no sentence in $T$ uses symbols from both $S_1\sqcup S_2$, then the $S_1$-reducts of models of $T$ are exactly the models of the $S_1$-part of $T$. (cont'd)

Comment: Technically we want to assume that there are no finite models of either the $S_1$-part or $S_2$-part of $T$, but that's an assumption we're happy to make here (I left out that neither $K_1$ nor $K_2$ should contain finite models, in my initial comment; but, in fact, it's not even necessary for the construction to work - it just cleans up the proof a little).